# Dead scientist revived in a power armor/exoskeleton (liquid keeps him alive, sealed in the suit)?

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

This movie is from the 1980s. There is a scientist that dies in a lab accident. He gets placed in a power suit and the liquid inside the suit revives him. Keeping him alive, sealed in the suit. An evil guy puts on a new, improved, power suit and then ends up killed when the scientist drowns him with the liquid from the power suit. The scientist dies because the liquid leaks out of the damaged suit.

Does anyone remember the name of this movie?

Comment: sorry doens't ring a bell. If you have enough patience you could look through: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science_fiction_films_of_the_1980s

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is called "[The Vindicator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhoC_fmIknc)."

I saw it as well and remembered the power suit was a prototype space suit and that helped track it down.

Here is the "[Vindicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vindicator_%28film%29)" wikipedia page.

Comment: If this is ever confirmed, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187661/made-for-tv-scifi-movie-scientist-becomes-prototype-cyborg-fights-another-c?noredirect=1&lq=1 as well as a few other times this film has come up.