# Made-for-tv(?) scifi movie. Scientist becomes prototype cyborg. Fights another cyborg

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

I remember seeing this a a boy. The main guy was a scientist. I think he was working on an adaptive suit or possibly a cyborg. He becomes the prototype. I do not remember it all but I know if he is touched he gets defensive automatically and he cannot control it. There is a battle between him and another cyborg like himself. He loses power and at the end, shows him in a displaycase.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: This sounds like The Vindicator.

Comment: Thanks Valorum, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The Vindicator (1986)

> An employee of a secret company operation becomes the victim of the company's special weapons project. He is transformed into a robotic killing machine that, because of his programming must destroy anything that comes near him.  <sup>[source](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092172/)</sup>

I remember watching this movie: The main character, Carl is a scientist in a robotic company that also works on a behavioural conditioning, that turns even mildest creature into a violent killer when touched (early scene shows a chimpanzee that turns suddenly violent when touched by a toy truck). Carl's boss Alex arranges an accident in which Carl is officially killed - but in truth Carl is turned into a cyborg with the "kill on touch" software. Carl manages to escape in a garbage truck, but he gets severely damaged by incinerator (for the rest of the movie he keeps constantly losing white "blood").

Comment: You can see the "display case" scene at the end of the film. He's actually in a museum display, but it's pretty similar.