# Movie about certain people being hunted by an unstoppable robotic alien figure in what looked like a biker helmet

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to think of a movie I saw about 30 years ago.

I can't think of the name but I remember scenes of this robotic alien figure, in what looked like a biker helmet, that's unstoppable and hunting down certain people. It has a thin transparent spike come out of its arm, while in the backseat of a vehicle, that goes through the front seat and through a woman's neck.

It seemed like a sci-fi thriller. Does anyone know what this movie is?

It's not any of the following:

- *Hardware* (1990)
- *Saturn 3* (1980)
- *Moontrap* (1988)
- *Terminator 2: Judgment Day* (1991)

Comment: I sort of remember it looking kinda like the Wraith. It couldve been a tv movie from the 80s or 90s.

Comment: _[The Vindicator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwGH1KIErG4)_ (1986) is only a partial match, but it's closer than any of the suggestions so far. It involves a man rebuilt as a cyborg with black armour and a helmet with a partial face mask killing people on Earth. He doesn't stab a needle through the back of a woman's neck in a car, but another character does that about halfway through the film.

Comment: I originally thought it was The Vindicator, but I couldnt find that scene. Maybe I’ll have to rewatch it and see if I was thinking of the other character you mentioned.

Comment: I provided a link to the full movie on YouTube in my previous comment. [Here's a direct link to the needle scene](https://youtu.be/KwGH1KIErG4?t=2663), if you want to check that part specifically.

Comment: thats it! it happens at about 44:25. thank you. been trying to think of this movie for a while now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As confirmed by a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/277586/movie-about-certain-people-being-hunted-by-an-unstoppable-robotic-alien-figure-i#comment765602_277586) from the OP, this is ***[The Vindicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vindicator_(film))*** (1986).

> *The Vindicator* (also known as *Frankenstein '88* and known in Brazil as *Roboman*) is a 1986 Canadian science fiction film directed by Jean-Claude Lord. The film is a modern-day retelling of the classic Frankenstein story set in the 1980s. Its plot involves a man who was killed in an accident in a laboratory, but revived as part of an experiment as a cyborg.

The film involves a man rebuilt as a cyborg with black armour and a helmet with a face mask killing people on Earth. He doesn't stab a needle through the back of a woman's neck in a car, but another character does that about halfway through the film.

I've only posted a trailer below, but the full film is currently uploaded on YouTube, and the needle scene can be viewed at around the 44:23 mark.

Comment: If so, it is a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187661/made-for-tv-scifi-movie-scientist-becomes-prototype-cyborg-fights-another-c?noredirect=1&lq=1